# why rename function in c++ isn't working?

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to do some testings for a project that I'm working on. I tried to rename a file and it doesn't work at all, what am I doing wrong?

I already tried to check the `close()` and `remove()` functions.

```
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream guy;
    

    guy.open("testing.txt", fstream::out);

    guy << "i love halav" << endl;


    fstream guy1;
    guy1.open("test1.txt", fstream::out);

    guy1 << "i love halav" << endl;
    

    guy.close();
    guy1.close();
    remove("testing.txt");

    int result = rename("testing1.txt", "testing.txt"); 
    if (result == 0)
        cout << "File successfully renamed" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Error renaming file" << endl;

    guy1.close();

    return 0;






}
```

**edit:** i edit the code so it will be more cear, again its not working .
the rearult im expecting is that the content of newFile.txt wil be "this is oldFile"

```
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream guy;
    

    guy.open("oldFile.txt", fstream::out );

    guy << "this is oldFile" << endl;


    fstream guy1;
    guy1.open("newFile.txt", fstream::out );

    guy1 << "this is newFile" << endl;
    

    guy.close();
    guy1.close();
    

    std::rename("oldFile.txt", "newFile.txt");
    remove("oldFile.txt");
    
        
    return 0;






}
```

Comment: If `rename` fails, it should set `errno` to the reason. You can use `perror` to print a readable error message too. Post the resulting information, and then maybe we can help you.

Comment: `rename` function is part of the C header. In C++, you would use `std::filesystem`.

Comment: "Doesn't work at all" is a rather vague problem statement. Maybe you got a typo there? You create "testing.txt" and "test1.txt", then remove "testing.txt" and try to rename "testing1.txt" that probably doesn't exist. Should "test1.txt" be "testing1.txt"? Can you give expected and actual results please?

Comment: Wrong arguments, it is rename(oldname, newname).  So swap them.

Comment: If you are using [rename(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html), you should read its documentation and tag your question with `Linux` or `POSIX`. In all cases provide some [mre] in your questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: With your edited question, you've shifted from one problem to another that renders any answers you've gotten more or less useless. Please don't do that. When you've overcome one problem and find another, ask a new question. Note that for your original question and my answer, you'd gotten `testing.txt` renamed to `testing1.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`std::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename) your first argument is supposed to be the *old* filename and the second argument is supposed to be the *new* filename. You've swapped the arguments, so try:

```
std::rename("testing.txt", "testing1.txt");
```

... but don't `std::remove("testing.txt");` before you rename the file since it'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

now thats the way to do it, thanks everyone!

```
  #include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream guy;
    

    guy.open("oldFile.txt", fstream::out );

    guy << "this is oldFile" << endl;


    fstream guy1;
    guy1.open("newFile.txt", fstream::out );

    guy1 << "this is newFile" << endl;
    

    guy.close();
    guy1.close();
    
    remove("newFile.txt");

    std::rename("oldFile.txt", "newFile.txt");
    
    
        
    return 0;






}
```